# How to inject an interface non managed by spring into a spring component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

im relatively new to spring framework and facing a challenge currently.

I have an interface ABC from an external library with me and a class BCD.
Now, i need to use ABC in my class. But when i autowire it, it always comes as null and throws NPE. ABC is not annotated.

```
Constructor in BCD required a bean of type ABC that could not be found.
```

Please let me know if this is something that is poosible with spring & guide me in the right direction!!

Note - This is not inject spring bean in non-spring managed bean but the other way around.
ABC is not managed by spring and BCD is a @Component class.

Thanks in Advance!!

```
import SampleInterface from from a maven dependency

@Component
public class ABC {
    
    @Autowire
    private SampleInterface SI;

    // Do my stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a class that's annotated with `@Configuration` (a new one or an existing one). In that class, add a method that returns an instance of `ABC` and annotate that method with `@Bean`. This will turn the return value into a Spring bean that you can then inject anywhere.

Comment: Issue is ABC in my scenario is an external code library and not my implementation. So on returning instance for that interface, im not sure which implementation to send.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the interface comes from, that's the benefit of using `@Bean` - you can return anything from anywhere. Which implementation to use is a different issue. There may be implementations provided, possibly through a factory method somewhere, or maybe you need to create one yourself. You need to check the API's documentation.

Comment: This worked!!! Was able to autowire it properly. Thank you so much for the answer. Appreciation++;